# Bundling NuxtJS dist directory using go:embed

Tags: go, nuxt.js

I have a web app using a NuxtJS frontend being served from a Golang `web` micro-service.

I am using `go:embed dist` to ship the frontend assets into the `web` binary and running it all in a Docker container. For non-Gophers, `go:embed` is a directive that bundles files or directories into the Go binary. It's a compile error to use `go:embed` on a directory that doesn't exist.

Usually, you don't commit the `dist` directory to VCS, but if I don't, then all my CI builds fail because I cannot compile the `web` service since `dist` doesn't exist.

I tried adding a `.gitignore` inside the dist folder like this:

```
*
!.gitigore
```

I was hoping this would commit the empty `dist` folder to VCS, but still not commit any of the assets. This worked fine, until I ran the NuxtJS build and it deleted the `.gitignore`. I assume it deletes the whole directory and recreates it.

Does anybody know whether there is a configuration option to keep the `dist` folder around between builds, or at least to not delete the `.gitignore` within it?

Comment: you're supposed to rebuild the assets as part of the CI pipeline